# Evaluating expression in Lua in Mathematics Environment

Tags: lua, environment-variables, environment, evaluation

I want to  write a function to evaluate mathematical expression in mathematics environment. Here is my attempt.

```
function mathEval(...)
 local _ENV = math
 return ...
end

print(mathEval(sin(0)))
```

This gives error that sin is nil, though environment is set to math. I know I could do it by setting global environment to math. But I don't want to pollute global space. My requirement is fairly simple. I want to write a function to evaluate mathematical expression in  local mathematics environment. Could it be easily done in lua without polluting global space?

Comment: In the statement `print(mathEval(sin(0)))`, you actually need `sin` to be set in the global environment (or local to the file). There's no way to create a special context that's only used in specific function calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the whole expression a string and then use `load` to execute the expression.

```
function mathEval(exp)
  return load("return " .. exp, exp, "t", math)()
end

print(mathEval("sin(0)"))
print(mathEval("sin(0)+cos(1)+2^2"))
```

Output in lua 5.3

> 0.0
>
> 4.5403023058681

You would need to use `loadstring` if your using 5.1

References for `load` function:

> https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a function `mathEval`:

```
setmetatable(_ENV,{__index=math})
print(sin(rad(30)))
print(sqrt(2))
print(pi)
```

This does not pollute the global space, in the sense that it does not create new globals.

Comment: Thanks for providing this. Is there a difference between `_ENV,{__index=math}` or  `_G,{__index=math}`? Either works. I may need to evaluate same free variable in different environments. What can be done in this case?

Comment: @Maths89, `_ENV` is the current environment where global names are resolved. Its default value is the same as `_G`, so no difference unless you change `_ENV` by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done, but you need to pass the name of the function (and parameters), as right now you are calling the function in the global environment, where it's not set up.

Something like this may work:

```
function mathEval(name, ...)
  local _ENV = math
  return _ENV[name](...)
end
print(mathEval("sin", 0))
```

Comment: I can't afford this. For example, I may need to evaluate `mathEval(sin(0)+cos(1)+2^2)`

Comment: Then you'll need to write it as `mathEval("sin(0)+cos(1)+2^2")` and evaluate in the context of the `math` environment (inside the function). What you are trying to do is not possible (unless you map `math` to the environment where mathEval is called). Another option is to use `mathEval(function() return sin(0)+cos(1)+2^2 end)` and call that function with a proper environment, but I think it will require passing _ENV to it.