# Evaluating expression in Lua in an Environment

Tags: lua, environment-variables, environment, evaluation

This question has some reference to the question [Evaluating expression in Lua in Mathematics Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368698)
The following code works.

```
tbl = {}
tbl.sin = math.sin
tbl.cos = math.cos

function mathEval(exp)
  return load("return " .. exp, exp, "t", tbl)()
end

print(mathEval("sin(0)"))
print(mathEval("sin(0)+cos(1)+2^2"))
```

However, the following code does not work.

```
tbl = {}
tbl.sin = math.sin
tbl.cos = math.cos

function mathEval(exp)
  return load("return " .. tostring(exp), tostring(exp), "t", tbl)()
end

print(mathEval(sin(0)))
print(mathEval(sin(0)+cos(1)+2^2))
```

I want to evaluate expressions without using quotes. How can that be done?

Comment: Should have asked for clarification before answering, but why those restrictions? Can you evaluate the expression directly, e.g. `r = sin(0)+cos(1)+2^2`? Can you modify the expression to access your tbl (`tbl.sin(0)+tbl.cos(1)+2^2`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with the line `print(mathEval(sin(0)+cos(1)+2^2))` is that the argument of `mathEval` is evaluated *before* `mathEval` runs, so evaluating the variables `sin` and `cos` can not be deferred to the environment of `mathEval`; that is, `mathEval` gets a value, and no expression to evaluate at all!

First of all, one option to evaluate such mathematical expressions *without* the use of `mathEval` would be to simply temporarily change your environment:

```lua
local prev_env = _ENV -- this is needed to restore the environment later on
_ENV = tbl -- enter custom environment
local result = sin(0)+cos(1)+2^2
_ENV = prev_env -- restore environment
print(result)
```

if you want `mathEval` as a convenience helper, you'll have to pass the expression *as a function returning the value to the expression* such that calling the function will evaluate the expression; this allows you to *defer* the initialization. You'll have to use a powerful function called `setfenv` which allows you to change the environment of `func`; this was unfortunately removed in favor of `_ENV` in Lua 5.2 and later. The code then becomes trivial:

```lua
local function mathEval(func)
    setfenv(func, tbl)
    return func
end
mathEval(function() return sin(0)+cos(1)+2^2 end)
```

`setfenv` can be replicated in Lua 5.2 using the `debug` library, since Lua internally implements `_ENV` as an upvalue, as [shown by Leafo](https://leafo.net/guides/setfenv-in-lua52-and-above.html):

```lua
local function setfenv(fn, env)
  local i = 1
  while true do
    local name = debug.getupvalue(fn, i)
    if name == "_ENV" then
      debug.upvaluejoin(fn, i, (function()
        return env
      end), 1)
      break
    elseif not name then
      break
    end

    i = i + 1
  end

  return fn
end
```

Comment: 'tbl = {}
tbl.sin = math.sin
tbl.cos = math.cos

function myeval(exp)
local prev_env = _ENV
_ENV = tbl
local result = exp
_ENV = prev_env
return result
end

myeval(sin(0))

Comment: I want to use it in above fashion. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: It's the problem we all mentioned, you are executing your expression BEFORE passing anything to myeval. At that moment sin is not known. You can either wrap it into a function or use the first approach shown by LMD.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you do not want to evaluate the expression before passing the result as an argument? Then you could wrap your expression into a function, which is then lazily called. It replaces the environment with `tbl`, executes the function, and reverts the environment.

```lua
tbl = {}
tbl.sin = math.sin
tbl.cos = math.cos

function mathEval(func)
    local old = _ENV
    _ENV = tbl
    local r = func()
    _ENV = old
    return r
end

print(mathEval(function() return sin(0)+cos(1)+2^2 end))
```

Comment: Note: This works because `mathEval` and the function use the same `_ENV` upvalue, so changing it for `mathEval` also changes it for the anonymous function. This means that it may fail if `mathEval` is in a different chunk, using a different `_ENV` upvalue than the anonymous function passed to `mathEval`, e.g. when requiring it: `require("mathEval"); print(mathEval(function() return sin(42) end))`